# Using variables in laravel blade template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Could anyone help me to understand how to use variables in the following case:

```
@for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++)
                    @if(isset($images->image_$i_url))
                        <div class="w-25" >
                            <img src="{{ Storage::url($images->image_$i_url) }}" alt="image" style="width: 128px;">
                        </div>
                    @endif
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="custom-file">
                                <input name="product_image_{{ $i }}" type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="product_image_{{ $i }}">
                                <label class="custom-file-label" for="exampleInputFile">Choose file</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        @error("product_image_{{ $i }}")
                        <div class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
                        @enderror
                @endfor
```

It doesn't work for $i

Answer (score 1):

If I get correctly, you have a problem with this line:

```
{{ Storage::url($images->image_$i_url) }}
```

Particularly:

```
$images->image_$i_url
```

Which is not solved to:

```
$images->image_0_url
$images->image_1_url
...
```

Technically, you cannot put **$** symbols as part of property name when you call it.

Therefore, a trick is by using '{}'

```
$images->{'image_' . $i . '_url'};
```

Full line example:

```
<img src="{{ Storage::url($images->{'image_' . $i . '_url'}) }}" alt="image" style="width: 128px;">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead. Loop through the collection of images. Whenever you want to reference the index of the loop, use $loop->index. This will scale better than using a hard-coded for loop.

```php
@foreach ($images as $image)

     @if ($image->url)

          <div class="w-25" >
               <img src="{{ Storage::url($image->url) }}" alt="image" style="width: 128px;">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
               <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="custom-file">
                         <input name="product_image_{{$loop->index}}" type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="product_image_{{$loop->index}}">
                         <label class="custom-file-label" for="exampleInputFile">Choose file
                         </label>
                     </div>
               </div>
               @error("product_image_{{$loop->index}}")
                   <div class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
               @enderror
          </div>
     @endif     
@endforeach
```

Comment: Special thanks for the 
`$loop->index`

Comment: @Evg127 No problem, there's a lot you can do with $loop, it is super cool. Check it out: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#loops

Answer (score 0):

You just want to iterate on three images?

```html
@foreach(['image_1_url', 'image_2_url', 'image_3_url'] as $image)
   @if(isset($images->$image))
      <div class="w-25" >
        <img src="{{ Storage::url($images->$image) }}" alt="image style="width: 128px;">
      </div>

// etc as before

@endforeach
```